# I am trying to create a kotlin project with intellij idea But can't create kotlin file under src file

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea

I want to open a kotlin file on a blank screen and work. However, as seen in the 2nd image, the kotlin-file/class tab does not appear.

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you check the box to create sample code in the project create screen you'll see where your code is supposed to go: src/main/kotlin

Answer (score 1):

Inside the `src` folder you have a `main` folder, which is followed by a `kotlin` folder which will likely appear blue. This means it's a **source root**. IntelliJ will only allow you to create code files in a source root.

[image: Source root example]